# Non-case sensitive Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I'm new in Flutter and have been trying to find a solution for this, but is there a way I can just accept the username ignoring if it's lowercase or uppercase? As long as it matches with their username it's fine to proceed.

```
  Widget emailField() {
    return TextFormField(
      textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
      keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
      focusNode: emailNode,
      validator: validateEmpty,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        hintText: 'Username',
        prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.account_circle),
        labelStyle: Label,
        fillColor: Colors.transparent,
      ),
      //validator: validateEmail,
      onSaved: (String? value) {
        email = value as String;
      },
    );
  }
```

```
submit() async {
    if (formKey1.currentState!.validate()) {
      formKey1.currentState!.save();

      if (_prefs.userSession!.username == email) {
        EasyLoading.instance.userInteractions = false;
        EasyLoading.show(status: 'Deleting account...');

        final response = await authService.masterDelete();
        if (_prefs.userSession!.username != email) {
          AwesomeDialog(
            context: context,
            dialogType: DialogType.ERROR,
            title: 'ERROR',
            desc: 'Incorrect username',
            btnCancelText: 'Accept',
            btnCancelOnPress: () {},
          ).show();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's only about ignoring lowercase/uppercase, then use `toLowerCase()` on both strings and compare them:

```
String mailOne = "TeSt123@gmail.com";
String mailTwo = "test123@gMAIL.com";
print(mailOne.toLowerCase() == mailOne.toLowerCase()); // -> true
```